# cocoa pods not work on mac OS X seirra

Tags: macos, cocoapods

I tried type this line in terminal "sudo gem install cocoapods -V"
"and sudo gem install cocoapods" ,

And it fetch hundreds lines in about half hour in terminal with error happened as the following lines :

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::ENOTDIR)
    Not a directory - /usr/local/bin/pod

i'm working on Sierra OS X and i want to use Pods with Xcode i tried different ways to disable root protection with no wish ,

In my other iMac with OS X Capitan i didn't phase any issue with the cocoapods it's was worked fine with me,

please help

Answer (score 7):

I found the solution by do the following :

- open terminal
- use terminal as root user and enter **sudo -i**
- enter your password
- type this line **sudo gem install cocoapods -V**

Cocoapods installed success in my mac

to close .

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command Also

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```